# Creating a "disabled" look by using a mask

Tags: html

I'm trying to create the following:

[image]

Using two images: one as mask (the diagonal lines) and the other the image and text themselves (the mask and image+text are the same size):

[image]  [image]

..and I just can't get it done!

I've tried all combinations with divs and z-indeces, opacity and background-image.. (should mention I'm noob to html).

Here's one shot I got at it (with only the mask and an image):

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 775px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 188px;
    width: 272px;
    background-image: url('grey-out.png');
}

img {
    z-index: 1000; 
}
```

---

```
<div></div>
<img src="41_large.png" />
```

Which just gives the diagonal lines themselves..
Can someone please help me out?
How do I make that "disabled" look combining the (semi-transparent) mask and the div?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it much more readable (for us who are trying to help you) when you use CSS rules instead of the style attribute?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: First time I ask an html question and one of the first I write html... Sorry.. And thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach works:

```
<div id="pspThing" class="disabled">
    <img class="disabled" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCTVr.png" />
</div>

#pspThing {
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpgNy.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 93px;
    width: 273px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#pspThing img {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#pspThing img.disabled {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zASzL/1/)

Bearing in mind that there's no transparency in your striped png (so far as the [imgur hosted image is concerned, anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCTVr.png), so I'm using `opacity` instead). Also the JS Fiddle demo's a little more complicated than necessary, so's I could show the disabled/enabled states.

Answer (score 2):

Pleass consider this simple snippet. Very universal solution. Acts and feels very much like the 'disable' attribute of input elements. See the snippet

```js
function disable(elementId, enabling) {

  el = document.getElementById(elementId);


  if (enabling) {
    el.classList.remove("masked");
  } else

  {
    el.classList.add("masked");
  }
}
```

```css
.masked {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: inline-block;
  //visibility:hidden; /* Uncomment this for complete disabling  */
}
.masked::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  //background: url('http://i.imgur.com/lCTVr.png'); /* Uncomment this  to use the image */
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('Now, click \'OK\' then \'Tab\' key to focus next button.\nThen click \'Enter\' to activate it.');">Test</button>
<div id="div1" style="display:inline-block" class="masked">
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button>
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button><br/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button>
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button><br/>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpgNy.jpg">
</div>
<button>Dummy</button>

<br/>
<button id="enableBtn" onclick="disable('div1',true);disable('enableBtn',false);disable('disableBtn',true);">Enable</button>
<button id="disableBtn" onclick="disable('div1',false);disable('enableBtn',true);disable('disableBtn',false);"  class="masked">Disable</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I built an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k4emic/L5V3a/).
I doubt that the position:absolute approach is the best way to handle this since you need to know the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

For doing it by z-index your both images should be in the container with img tag.